# Understanding the geometry response in HERE API

Tags: here-api

I am trying to get road geometry from here API request of the form:
`https://s.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/1/tile.json?layer=ROAD_GEOM_FC3&level=11&tilex=2157&tiley=1620&apiKey={MY_API_KEY}`

Here is a typical geometry response:

```
LAT “5246282,,1,1,1”
LON “960310,30,24,13,10"
```

How exactly to understand this?

I am assuming the first point is `52.46282, 9.60310` but what's the logic behind this? And what do the next numbers in the comma mean?

A solution using the above numbers would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this request:

> [https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/1/doc/layer.json?apiKey={{HERE_API_KEY}}&layer=ROAD_GEOM_FC3](https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/1/doc/layer.json?apiKey=%7B%7BHERE_API_KEY%7D%7D&layer=ROAD_GEOM_FC3)

You can see that the attributes LAT and LON has this description:

> "Latitude coordinates [10^-5 degree WGS84] along the polyline. Comma
> separated. Each value is relative to the previous."

Example:
"5246282" has 5 decimals like 52.46282, the next value after the comma is a sum(positive value) or minus(negative value) on the previous value, like that: "5246282,5" = "52.46282,52.46287". If the next value is empty so repeat the last value again.

This means that:

```
LAT “5246282,,1,1,1”
LON “960310,30,24,13,10"
```

is like that:

```
LAT “52.46282,52.46282,52.46283,52.46284,52.46285”
LON “9.60310,9.60340,9.60364,9.60377,9.60387"
```